# Unable to detect a keyboard combination using pynput inside the wx.adv.TaskBarIcon class

Tags: python, wxpython, taskbar, pynput

I need a taskbar app to responde not only to the mouse clicks which is not a problem but also on a specific keyboard keys combination (hot key).

I'm very new to Python, so I tried a sample based on wx.adv, and tried to incorporate there the listener from pynput. The code doesn't work, and I get an error that on_press is not defined.

```
KeyComb_My = [
    {pynput.keyboard.Key.ctrl, pynput.keyboard.KeyCode(char='s')},
    {pynput.keyboard.Key.ctrl_l, pynput.keyboard.KeyCode(char='s')},
    {pynput.keyboard.Key.ctrl_r, pynput.keyboard.KeyCode(char='s')}
             ]

class TaskBarIcon(wx.adv.TaskBarIcon):
    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.frame = frame
        super(TaskBarIcon, self).__init__()
        self.set_icon(TRAY_ICON)
        self.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_TASKBAR_LEFT_DOWN, self.on_left_down)
        self.keyb_listener()

    def CreatePopupMenu(self):
        menu = wx.Menu()
        create_menu_item(menu, 'Site', self.on_click)
        menu.AppendSeparator()
        create_menu_item(menu, 'Exit', self.on_exit)
        return menu

    def set_icon(self, path):
        icon = wx.Icon(path)
        self.SetIcon(icon, TRAY_TOOLTIP)

    def on_left_down(self, event):      
        print ('Tray icon was left-clicked.')

    def on_click(self, event):
        frame = MyForm()
        frame.Show()

    def on_exit(self, event):
        wx.CallAfter(self.Destroy)
        self.frame.Close()

    def on_press(self, key):
        print(key)
        if any([key in comb for comb in KeyComb_My]):
            current.add(key)
            if any(all(k in current for k in comb) for comb in 
            KeyComb_My):
                print("Start")
                frame = MyForm()
                frame.Show()

    def on_release(self, key):
        try:
           current.remove(key)
        except KeyError:
            pass    

    def keyb_listener(self):
        current = set()
        listener = pynput.keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, 
        on_release=on_release)
        listener.start()
```

I expected that the defined key combination will launch on_press and open another window (MyForm). However the actual output is an error.

Comment: Research about `self` in Python classes. You need your `current` to be `self.current`, those arguments to Listener to be `on_press=self.on_press, on_release=self.on_release`, etc.

Comment: Thank you. This helped although I'm still confused about use of 'self' in Python classes.